# ionic input insert with ion-toggle instead of button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I would very much like to combine an [item-input-inset](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#item-input-inset) with an [ion-toggle](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionToggle/) instead of the button - so the user can choose to disable the input field.

What I want is something like this:

[image]

I do wish to connect the text input to a model so I always have a variable that is `Not Applicable` or some other string that the user entered (or empty).

But my first problems has been the layout that seems to mess up. This is how far I got:

```
  <div class="item item-input-inset">
        <label class="item-input-wrapper">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Text input">
        </label>
        <ion-toggle>
        </ion-toggle>
      </div>
  </div>
```

gives the following messed up layout

[image]

Comment: Plunker? or css code for item-input-wrapper?

Comment: There are some answer already, check it out @Norfeldt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Norfeldt: Please check the snippet below and let me know your thought. Hope it works as your expectation.

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  //INIT checked false
  $scope.toggleInput = {
    checked: false
  };
  $scope.toggleInputChange = function() {
    //TO DO
  };
});
```

```css
body {
  cursor: url('http://ionicframework.com/img/finger.png'), auto;
}
.item-toggle .toggle {
  top: 18px !important;
}
.item-toggle input[type='text'] {
  pointer-events: all;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.item-toggle input[type="text"]:disabled {
  font-weight: 100;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

<body ng-app="ionicApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <ion-content>
      <ion-toggle ng-model="toggleInput.checked" ng-change="toggleInputChange()">
        <input ng-disabled="!toggleInput.checked" type="text" ng-model="userInput.value" placeholder="{{toggleInput.checked ? 'This is the user input...' : 'Not Applicable' }}">
      </ion-toggle>
    </ion-content>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a really good answer.. Thank you. Looks good on StackOverflow. Just need to test it in with ionic

Comment: How is this going on mobile app? I have just back from holiday :D

Comment: had to modify your code a bit to get what I wanted, but you helped me archive the goal. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Would is it possible to use an variable in the expression for the placeholder , like this `{{toggleInput.checked ? '{{foo}}' : 'Not Applicable' }}`?

Comment: If your controller have $scope.foo. Just let it as
{{toggleInput.checked ? foo : 'Not Applicable' }}

Answer (score 2):

Hope it will help you.

**Required CSS**

```
.item-toggle input[type='text'] {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

**Template Code:**

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-toggle ng-model="pushNotification.checked"
                ng-change="pushNotificationChange()">
     <input ng-disabled="!pushNotification.checked" type="text" ng-model="userInput.value" placeholder="{{placeholder}}">
    </ion-toggle>

</ion-content>
```

**Controller Code**

```
var temp = '';
$scope.placeholder = 'Not Applicable';
$scope.pushNotificationChange = function() {

   if($scope.pushNotification.checked) {
      $scope.userInput.value = temp;
    }
  else {
     temp =  $scope.userInput.value;
     $scope.userInput.value = '';
   }
 };

 $scope.pushNotification = { checked: false };
 $scope.userInput = {value:''};
```

Check this plunker http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XKzaBo

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you apply the following CSS:

```
.item-toggle {
    padding: 0;
    border-width: 0;
}

.item-toggle .toggle {
    position: inherit;
    top: inherit;
    right: inherit;
}
```

See http://play.ionic.io/app/8a0cf8a27f4e.